# React Native: Dismiss keyboard does not work with search bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactjs, keyboard, react-native

I am looking for a way to **implement functionality to hide keyboard for native looking search bar** in react native (iOS).

There is a possible conflict between react native packages `react-native-dismiss-keyboard` and `react-native-search-bar`. Dismiss keyboard works for `<TextInput>`, but not for `<SearchBar>` elements.

How to achieve the desired functionality?

Import:

```
import dismissKeyboard from 'react-native-dismiss-keyboard';
```

Doesn't work:

```
<SearchBar
  onChangeText={dismissKeyboard}
  onSearchButtonPress={dismissKeyboard}
  onCancelButtonPress={dismissKeyboard} />
```

Works:

```
<TextInput
  onChange={dismissKeyboard} />
```